# Form returns incorrect value of a datefield in ExtJS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1urn), which reproduces what looks like a bug. So, this is the html code I have:

```
<div id="btn"></div>
<div id="datefield"></div>
```

I then render ExtJS components to these divs like so:

```
    var id = Ext.id();
    Ext.create('Ext.Button',{
        text: 'Get value',
        renderTo: 'btn',
        handler: function () {
            alert(JSON.stringify(Ext.getCmp(id).getForm().getFieldValues()));
        }
    });
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
        renderTo: 'datefield',
        id: id,
        items:[{
            xtype: "datefield",
            startDay:"1",
            format:"d.m.Y"
        }]
    });
```

And when I set datefield value to current date and press `Get value` button, I get a value which differs from what I set. Here is a screen proof:

[image]

What may be wrong and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

When I do this:

```
console.log(Ext.getCmp(id).getForm().getFieldValues());
```

I also see in the console this incorrect value:

[image]

So, the whole problem is not with `JSON.stringify`, but with `ExtJS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calling `JSON.stringify` method, `Date` objects converted into `UTC` format. You are selecting the date with your time zone, and when your serializing it to `JSON` you are getting the date value wihout timezone. From the alert message I can say that your timezone is GMT +3. So the form is returning right value.

Comment: Well, if I just console.log(Ext.getCmp(id).getForm().getFieldValues()), without using JSON.stringify, I also see this incorrect value.

Comment: This is what I get when change `alert` statement to `console.log` form values without `JSON.stringify`  - `Object {datefield-1010-inputEl: Sat Apr 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Caucasus Standard Time)}` You can see that at the end of the date object there is timezone applied

Comment: I've just checked it in my timezone with the same value and again see incorrect value. So, there is some trouble with ExtJS and I guess I need some fix.

Comment: execute this code in your browser's console, what you are getting? `console.log(new Date())`

Comment: I see this `Date 2017-04-29T09:57:19.841Z`

Comment: No, it's incorrect. In my timezone its should be 12:58 instead of 09:57

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142959/discussion-between-ruben-vardanyan-and-jacobian).